# Remove differences between two video frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to remove the differences between two frames and keep the non-chaning graphics. Would probably repeat the same process with more frames to get more accurate results. My idea is to simplify the frames removing things that won't need to simplify the rest of the process that will do after.

The different frames are coming from the same video so no need to deal with different sizes, orientation, etc. If the same graphic its in another frame but with a different orientation or scale, I would like to also remove it. For example:

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

Result (more or less, I suppose that will be uglier but containing a similar information)
[image: Result]

One of the problems of this idea is that the source video, even if they are computer generated graphics, is compressed so its not that easy to identify if a change on the tonality of a pixel its actually a change or not.

Im ideally not looking at a pixel level and given the differences in saturation applied by the compression probably is not possible. Im looking for unchaged "objects" in the image. I want to extract the information layer shown on top of whats happening behind it.

During the last couple of days I have tried to achieve it in a Python script by using OpenCV with all kinds of combinations of absdiffs, subtracts, thresholds, equalizeHists, canny but so far haven't found the right implementation and would appreciate any guidance. How would you achieve it?

Comment: So, you are wanting to keep parts of the two images that are the same.   The tricky part is how you appear to be defining "same":   it applies to objects rather than pixels.   You'll need to nail down this definition further...

Comment: I have modified it a bit, hope that its clearer. Let me know if thats not the case.

Comment: I think this is a hard problem in Computer Vision, in many respects.   What is the ultimate goal, e.g., learning the rules of the game  by "watching" play?   You *might* be able to come up with a more application-specific approach.

Comment: please provide a set of pictures, and the code, that cause you trouble. you need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

> Im ideally not looking at a pixel level and given the differences in saturation applied by the compression probably is not possible. Im looking for unchaged "objects" in the image. I want to extract the information layer shown on top of whats happening behind it.

This will be extremely hard. You would need to employ proper CV and if you're not an expert in that field, you'll have really hard time.

How about this, forgetting about tooling and libs, you have two images, ie. two equally sized sequences of RGB pixels. Image A and Image B, and the output image R. Allocate output image R of the same size as A or B.

Run a single loop for every pixel, read pixel `a` and from A and pixel `b` from B. You get a 3-element (RGB) vector. Find distance between the two vectors, eg. magnitude of a vector (`b`-`a`), if this is less than some tolerance, write either `a` or `b` to the same offset into result image R. If not, write some default (background) color to R.

You can most likely do this with some HW accelerated way using OpenCV or some other library, but that's up to you to find a tool that does what you want.